# import own .jar file as dependency via Maven and have install discover and retrieve it's dependencies

Tags: java, maven, jar

So this is probably a stupid question, but I have created an own library "testlib" which I want to include in other of my own Maven projects.

This is my own librarys .pom

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test.testlib</groupId>
    <artifactId>testlib</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}</name>
    <description>testlibrary</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.36</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

In order to include my library in another new project, I have created a local repository in my new projects .pom

```xml
...
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>data-local</id>
            <name>data</name>
            <url>file://${project.basedir}/repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test.testlib</groupId>
            <artifactId>testlib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
...
```

Installing my own library "testlib" via mvn install is working fine for testlib itself. The problem is, that Maven will not detect that "testlib" requires org.slf4j, hence won't get it when I run install.

I have checked other dependencies in my .m2 folder and saw they have a .pom file with the same name as the .jar (for log4j that'd be log4j-1.2.17.pom). I tried copying testlibs .pom next to its .jar and changed the name accordinly, but that doesn't do it.

What do I have to do in order to get the same functionality as any other library from maven central? In other words, I don't want a fat .jar that has all dependencies included. I want a Maven project that adds my library as a dependency to discover that it needs sl4j and include it when mvn install is run.

Comment: Why do you create your own repository? Why not use the local repository of your computer? BTW: Dependencies are loaded automatically.

Comment: The simplest thing is to do a `mvn install` in your `testlib` project...then write in the other project you like to use it simply a dependency with the appropriate names and that's it. No definition of a local repository etc. needed. Furthermore what is the reason for mentioning the maven-compiler-plugin ? If you like to mention it is better to define the version of the maven-compiler-plugin...